# jQuery Live Preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a problem, because I'm getting an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of null

It's about Live Updating of a Live Preview, just like writing something on Stack Overflow.

```js
function showPreview() {
  var myStickieText = $("#txtarea").text();

  myStickieText = myStickieText.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
  myStickieText = myStickieText.replace(/\[b\]/g, '<b>').replace(/\[\/b\]/g, '</b>');
  myStickieText = myStickieText.replace(/\[i\]/g, '<i>').replace(/\[\/i\]/g, '</i>');
  myStickieText = myStickieText.replace(/\[u\]/g, '<u>').replace(/\[\/u\]/g, '</u>');
  myStickieText = myStickieText.replace(/\[quote\]/g, '<div class="group_myPage_quote">').replace(/\[\/quote\]/g, '</div>');


  $("#livepreview").html(myStickieText);

}
```

```html
<div class="text-container" style="float:left; width:70%;">
  <textarea id="txtarea" name="txtarea" onkeypress="showPreview()"
            style="width:100%; height:135px; resize: none;">
  </textarea>


  <div class="livepreview" id="livepreview" style="margin-top:15px;"></div>

</div>
```

(*No, this is not a Duplicate, since I need a fix, not a complete new Solution.)*

Comment: Did you include jQuery in your page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting the value of the text area correctly.
It should be `val()` not `text()`:

Simply replace

`var myStickieText = $("#txtarea").text();`

with

`var myStickieText = $("#txtarea").val();`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, This gives me the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of null`

Comment: Well it shouldn't ,you're probably doing something else wrong or have a conflict. You're probably running the function before the element exists in the DOM (are you loading it via Ajax?)

Comment: I've checked everything, and this did fix it. Thank you for your Support.